# Stored Procedure debugging when using Aspose for a web site

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, aspose

I have no idea if this kind of setup is common or not. I don't have a full understanding yet of how everything hold together, so bear with me.

Our workplace is using these tools

- SQL Server that contains all our client data and we have quite a few stored procedure
- Share Point that contains

  - aspx files for the website
  - Word documents where all the website pages look is
- Aspose that glues everything together

So here's a small example to show how it works.

An aspx file will contain the path to the word document to load.
That word document contains a table, a button and a field for a date.
Aspose renders those objects in the word file in a web browser.

The button in the word document will call a stored procedure in SQL Server that will fill the table with all the users name that registered after the date provided.

Here I'm not entirely sure how everything holds together, but I know Aspose is doing it.

My question is this, how can I debug my stored procedure when I click on the button? I know how to debug a stored procedure directly from SQL Server, but because a call to that procedure is made from the web I cannot put any breakpoint in it.

As I mentioned, we have quite a few stored procedure. It would save me a lot of time if I could just do plain regular debuging. The logic is somewhat hard to follow in the code to simply do mental debug. 
I do not want to "fake execute" a procedure by calling it with specified parameters because I especially want to see what are the values passed to the procedures.

Should you need more information, feel free to ask. I may have omited details that I didn't thing were relevant.

Thank you

Comment: #1 use sql profiler to see what sql your app is ultimately executing.  #2 add trace/logging to the code you do control to inspect values as they happen. This is functionally much the same as what you do when you attach a debugger to step through code.

Comment: Also, you'll get better answers if this is something narrow- like how to attach a debugger to a running stored proc, invoked by some 3rd party process. That sounds difficult.